# How does DVD anti-piracy work?

Tags: dvd, copy-protection, compact-disc, piracy

I know this is a "general" question. I was wondering how 'console' anti-piracy works. Which CD/DVD sectors are written? Why a normal DVD burner can't write it?  Just curious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many copy protection schemes in use, explaining them all would be a long post, even if I knew how they all worked.

Obviously the companies that use them want to keep them a secret so it's harder to bypass, so you probably won't get much information from them.

You best bet is to check the CD/DVD copy forums, users there would have done some analysis to find out the best way to copy them.

[General info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_protection#Copy_protection_methods_of_recent_video_game_console_systems)

[Club MyCE forums](http://club.myce.com/f80/)

[Afterdawn forums](http://forums.afterdawn.com/group_view.cfm/24)